Open universal link when app is in background
I have a case with this problem iOS. When I click an universal link, when the app is in background, the below method not fired
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {}

Please see the cases summarised below

Associate domains are configured properly.
When tap a universal link, the app opens quickly without any issue.
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions), is calling all the time when the app launch.
When the app is in background, tapped on universal link,

 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String)

this method got fired. But with this method no way to get the tapped URL. so its hard to move to a particular feature.
Please help me to find out which method will be fired when tapping a universal link when the app is in background. I need to get the tapped URL to move forward.
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String)

currently this method got fired. but this is not helpful for me to move forward.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Have you implemented scene(_:continue)?

@Paulw11 yes implemented, but doesn't fired.
